# GWT Internationalisation encoding issue

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, internationalization

In my GWT application I have recently added german translations following the documentation by introducing .properties files and set the encoding according to the official documentation:

> > Encoding for international character sets
>
> When you internationalize your application’s interface, keep in mind
>   that the languages you support may contain characters not in the ASCII
>   character set. Therefore, both in the HTML host page
>   and the Java properties files that contain the
>   translations, you must set the encoding to UTF-8.

However althought it works for most characters, some characters are displayed as question marks. For example the character ä

Comment: I'm using a German localization and everything is working just fine. Are you sure the properties file is saved with UTF-8 encoding (without BOM!)? If you're editing the file in Eclipse for example, this might be a problem, because Eclipse doesn't save files with UTF-8 by default.

Comment: @Baz: I am editing the file in Eclipse but I have changed the encoding to UTF-8 in the file properties but still having the same problem.

Comment: @user1984695 Do you mean you changed the Eclipse properties? If you want to make sure that the encoding is correct, open the file in an editor like Notepad++ and double check. I had the problem before, that Eclipse was messing things up if you forget to change every necessary setting.